# Customização de mensagem Validator Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tenho o seguinte validador `cpfValidacao.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

class cpfValidacao
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        return $this->isValidate($attribute, $value);
    }

    protected function isValidate($attribute, $value)
    {
        $c = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value);
        if (strlen($c) != 11 || preg_match("/^{$c[0]}{11}$/", $c)) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($s = 10, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);
        if ($c[9] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($s = 11, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);
        if ($c[10] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Chamada no `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
/**
* Bootstrap any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{
   Validator::extend('cpf', '\App\Utils\cpfValidacao@validate');
}
```

Chamada no controller:

```
 /* validação de parâmetros */
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'email' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
     'cpf' => 'required|min:1|max:11|cpf',
     'name' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
     'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255'
     //'profile_picture_path' => 'required|min:1|max:255'
 ]);
 if($validator->fails()){
     $errors = $validator->errors();
     return response()->json(['error' => true, $errors], 422);
 }
 /* fim */
```

Retorno:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "0": {
        "cpf": [
            "validation.cpf"
        ]
    }
}
```

Quero customizar a mensagem `"validation.cpf"`. Como faz?

`Laravel 6.2`

Comment: O ideal seria você criar uma Rule mesmo sem precisar estender o service provider, lá você pode definir a mensagem que quiser, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Certo obrigado irmão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentado pelo Thiago, o ideal seria você criar uma [Rule](http://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) da seguinte forma:
Rodando o comando para criar o arquivo de validação em `app/rules`

```
php artisan make:rule CpfValidation
```

Na função passes colocar sua lógica:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $c = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value);
    if (strlen($c) != 11 || preg_match("/^{$c[0]}{11}$/", $c)) {
        return false;
    }
    for ($s = 10, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);
    if ($c[9] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
        return false;
    }
    for ($s = 11, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);
    if ($c[10] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

E na função mensage, a mensagem que você retornar caso dê erro de validação:

```
public function message()
{
    return 'Cpf inválido.';
}
```

Um exemplo de como usar a validação feita:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
 'email' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
 'cpf' => ['required', 'min:1', 'max:11', new CpfValidation],
 'name' => 'required|min:1|max:255',
 'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255'
 //'profile_picture_path' => 'required|min:1|max:255'
 ]);
```

Comment: Entendi. Fiz aqui e já funcionou. É possível adicionar mais de uma função no mesmo "`rules`"?

Comment: @LuizRobertoFurtuna senão tiver a ver com o CPF não é legal colocar junto porque aí você está desrespeitando o principio da responsabilidade única, sempre tente deixar as coisas separadas. então se precisar de outra regra, é só criar outra de novo